# Error statement for Autocorrelation structure in mixed model (R software)

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to model the evolution in time of one weed species (E. crus galli) within 4 different cropping systems (=treatment). I have 5 years of data spaced out equally in time and two repetitions (block) for each cropping system. Hence, block is a random factor. Measures were repeated each year on the same block (--> repeated measure mixed model). Zuur et al (2009) recommend to insert a correlation structure (corAR1, corARMA...). Which one would be the most adapted? I decided to go with corCAR1...

My model is the following:

```
## Data creation
syst=rep(c("CONV","LI","NT","SR"),10)
block=c(rep("b1",20),rep("b2",20))
year=rep(c(rep("2011",4),rep("2012",4),rep("2013",4),rep("2014",4),rep("2015",4)),2)
ECHCG=c(1,2,24,5,22,89,18,18,3,15,132,0,11,18,585,4,5,5,781,10,5,0,4,1,17,1,75,0,1,13,210,3,6,16,739,1,1,1,1089,0)
pi=data.frame(syst,block,year,ECHCG)

## Factor and numeric attribution ##
block=as.factor(block)
year=as.numeric(year)
syst=as.factor(syst)
ECHCG=as.numeric(ECHCG)

## Model specification ##
require(nlme)
MECHCG=lme(ECHCG~syst*year,random=~1|block,correlation=corCAR1(form=~year|block),data=pi)
```

Year is a covariate and block a grouping factor like the "form" argument specifies.

The problem is that "R" sends back this message:

> Error in Initialize.corCAR1(X[[i]], ...) :
>     la covariable doit avoir des valeurs uniques pour les intragroupes des objets "corCAR1"
>
> (ie, "The covariable has to have unique values for the intragroups of corCAR1 objects")

---

CORRECTION: To have unique values, you need to specify to the model that "syst" is nested in "block". That is to say:

```
MECHCG=lme(ECHCG~syst*year,random=~1|block/syst,correlation=corCAR1(form=~year|block/syst),data=pi)
```

Comment: This is a limitation of nlme. It needs exactly one value per `year | block` to be able to model the auto-correlation.

Comment: @Roland : Thank you. So right now i have four value per year|block (one for each system). How do i cope with this? Is there another function?

Comment: Btw., if you have only two blocks you are effectively estimating a variance based on two values. That's usually not a great idea. Consider using block as a fixed effect (that would also only add one parameter if you have two blocks).

Comment: Does the system and the block correspond to a specific plot? Then you could nest the two grouping variables (for the random effect and the correlation structure).

Comment: @Roland: There is two blocks and each system is randomized in each block.

Comment: So this is a random plot design and the plots were measured repeatedly? Then the plots nested in block are the subjects.

Comment: @Roland: Exactly. But the same message comes up when I do:   MECHCG=lme(ECHCG~syst*year,random=~1|block/syst,correlation=corCAR1(form=~year|block/syst),data=pi)

Comment: Then use `table` to check. You have more then one value for year/block/syst combinations.

Comment: @Roland: thank you so much, there was just a little loss in translation :)